# Adding dashboard header is not working in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am learning R Shiny, creating a project for learning purpose. I am unable to figure out how to had a dashboard header. I tried to add `dashboardheader()` part at the begining of the code after `fluidpage` but it doesnt work. I am unable to understand what is the mistake I am doing. can someone help me where to add dashboardheader part to the code below. Thank you in advance!

Code:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("united"),
                 
 
  titlePanel(HTML("<center>Sample - project</center>")),
  
  
  
  sidebarLayout(position="left",
    sidebarPanel( width = 3,
      
       selectizeInput("gruppe", "gruppe",
                     choices = rug$gruppe, selected="NONE", multiple = TRUE),
      selectizeInput("Allg_Infos", "auswählen",
                     choices = rug$Allg_Infos, selected="NONE", multiple = TRUE),
      selectizeInput("Schema", "Schema",
                     choices = rug$Schema, multiple = TRUE, options = list(maxItems = 6)),
                     submitButton("Submit"),
      
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Important",  tags$p(" "),
                 tags$li(("Many cannot be discontinued abruptly"),style="font-size: 20px"),
                 
                  ),
        
        tabPanel("Tplan",  tags$p(" "), tableOutput("Tplan"),
        
        tabPanel("Table",  tags$label(h3('Status/Output')), tableOutput("rug_data"),
                 hr(),
                 print("* Daily reductions "),
                 hr(),
                 print("** Weekly and daily reductions ") 
    
      ))))))
  
)
```

Comment: TBMK you can't simply add UI elements from shinydashboard in a shiny app. The reason is that shinydashboard requires additional HTML dependencies which are not included in a standard shiny app. See e.g. https://unleash-shiny.rinterface.com/htmltools-dependencies.html#htmldeps-import for more on this.

Comment: If I understood correct you would like to add header to the dashboard. You could add something like navbarpage refer to https://community.rstudio.com/t/separate-the-title-from-the-tabpanels-in-navbarpage/59355